# One hot encoding "got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

[[image: categories[0] does not seem to be working [1]]

[image: 0th column is what I'm trying to one hot encode]

> error :   oneHot = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0]) 
>   TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'categorical_features'.

I'm tring to encode first column
here's my code sample:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder 
labelen_x = LabelEncoder() # string to numeric encoding object
x[:,0]= labelen_x.fit_transform(x[:,0]) # replaces the string labels with numerics for ML algorithm to be able to work with it
oneHot = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
x = oneHot.fit_transform(x).toarray()
```

Comment: may be you can use pandas for this (much easier): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't pass any obejct while initialise OHE class, simply do:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder 

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0,1,2,3,0,1,2]})
colnames = ['col'] # modify this for your df

oneHot = OneHotEncoder()
x_ohe = oneHot.fit_transform(df[colnames].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

To check how the one-hot-encoded data looks (see matrix), simply do:

```
x_ohe.todense()
```

Comment: now the entire x got encoded in one hot and that's not what I want, I just want to encode first column into 3 binary encoded colmns

Comment: just pass the name of columns as a list, check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue, could not find the cause but be able to find an answer. Hope it would help. Further details can be taken from this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).
-Thanks-

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer([('any_name', OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder='passthrough')                        

X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype=np.float)
```

Answer (score 0):

With scikit-learn version `0.21.3` I'm able to get correct one-hot-encoding as follows:

[image]

As you can see with the warning, that the parameter `categorical_features` would be depreciated with sklearn version `0.22` onwards. So, you need to use `ColumnTransformer` instead. [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html) is the doc for `ColumnTransformer`

Comment: hey I'm not sure if that's what I want actually I want to encode the first column from x to three different columns for each say for 0: 1 0 0,for 1 : 0 1 0 and for 2 : 0 0 1 and keep the rest as it is

Comment: I'm performing the same operation - the first column (the same as yours) has been transformed to one-hot encoding format. The encoding is as follows: 0 -> 1 0 0; 1 -> 0 1 0 ; 2 -> 0 0 1. However, check if your `sklearn` version is over 0.22 and use `ColumnTransformer` if it is.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is just `categories`.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: can you please have another look at an edit in this post, I did just as u said

Comment: Because you have no variable by that name. The parameter, though is categories, not categorical_features

Answer (score 0):

This is the latest solution for the categorical_feature error.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
Label_x = LabelEncoder()
x[:,0] = Label_x.fit_transform(x[:,0])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder.categorical_features =[0]
OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(x).toarray()
x = x[:, 1:]
```